# Citing a paper for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, academia

I'm writing my thesis and I want to explain the logistic regression model. Is there a paper that introduced this model so I can cite it?

Comment: Cite the text from which you learned this technique should be sufficient. It is a very common technique and most of the times the seminal paper of it are not cited. Unless you are writing about, say, the history of logistic regression.

Comment: Here's a great [article on the origins of logistic regression](http://papers.tinbergen.nl/02119.pdf). Turns out it has it's roots in the early 1800s.

Answer (score 6):

McCullagh and Nelder's book "Generalized Linear Models" would be a good place to refer to for logistic regression.

Comment: even if I never read the book?!

Comment: You should read the book, or at least have a look at some of the parts on logistic regression. It's the kind of book that demystifies.

Comment: the problem is that I don't own the book or can find one to look at that section. So I was wondering if it is okay to just cite it ...

Answer (score 1):

I would cite the Hastie and Tibshirani book "The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction".

Comment: Why this particular book? It is not on logistic regression per se. Yes, you can cite literally any book that mentions logistic regression but if that is your answer then you should write so. McCullagh and Nelder's  "Generalized Linear Models" is the book that basically introduces the idea of GLM's.